# No funciona Live Share

Tags: github, vscode, extensiones

Tengo un problema a la hora de usar live share y no he podido encontrar la manera de solucionarlo;
El problema literalmente es que no funciona nada de la extensión, por ejemplo:

[image: Ejemplo de que no funciona]

Cuando le doy allí donde dice **share** no pasa nada, y lo mismo con todos los botones de la extension.
Y si quiero hacer lo mismo con el *f1* es decir asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tampoco funciona y me sale este error:

```
Command 'Live Share: Start Collaboration Session (Share)' 
resulted in an error (command 'liveshare.startFromWelcomeContent' not found)
```

Ya probe desinstalando y volviendo a instalar y el problema persiste, Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hace tiempo que no uso live share pero creo recordar que es necesario tener previamente el proyecto abierto para que funcione. No se si este es tu caso.

Answer (score 0):

justo tenia ese problema y pude solucionarlo desinstalando e eliminando la extension live share y live audio de la siguiente manera..
primero que todo desinstala la extension del vs code, luego dirigete a la carpeta donde se guardan la extensiones.
en mi caso uso Linux y se encuentra en la siguiente ubicacion

```
cd /home/username/.vscode/extensions
```

recuerda cambiar username por tu nombre de usuario, en mac debe ser algo similar, en windows no tengo conocimiento de como aparece pero puedes buscar en google donde se encuentran guardadas las extensiones del vs code.

una ves estes en esa ruta vas a desinstalar las extensiones que tenga relacion con live share, en mi caso son live share, live audio y live share pack y las desinstale de la siguiente manera, tener en cuenta el numero de la version que tengas instalada en ese momento por si quieres copiar y pegar el comando.

```
rm -r ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-1.0.5043 ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-audio-0.1.91 ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-pack-0.4.0
```

espero les sea de ayuda, comenten si pudieron solucionarlo.